# Is there any API or JNI wrapper that enables Glass to decode a raw H.264 video stream over a network?

Tags: google-glass

We are wondering if there is any API or JNI wrapper that enables Glass to decode raw H.264 video stream over network?
Our understanding is that API 16 has the MediaCodec api which supports En/Decoding of the H.264 format but since glass runs on API 15, it complains about media class not found.
We have also tried other third party libraries but of no avail.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your research is correct. This isn't something that's available as of on Glass a this time.

If this is something that you'd like GDK to support, please let Google know by [creating an issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) in the official issue tracker.